# Unable to find property file in classpath for gradle dist build

Tags: java, build, classpath, gradle, manifest

(new to gradle)

Java Program reads property files from classpath using the classloader getResourceAsStream function. The program runs in eclipse without errors. Executing the batch file generated from the distZip gradle task results in the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: property file 'prop.properties' not found in the classpath
    at com.foo.bar.fb.utility.PropResourceCache.getProperties(PropResourceCache.java:26)
    at com.foo.bar.fb.offline.RunOfflineProcess.main(RunOfflineProcess.java:40) Press any key to continue . . .
```

I assume this is due to the properties not being included in the manifest file. Is there a way to include all property files in the program's src/main/resources/Properties directory? Whats the best practice?

gradle build entry

```
jar.doFirst{
        manifest {
            attributes(
                "Manifest-Version"    : "1.0",
                "Built-By"            : System.getProperty('user.name'),
                "Built-Date"          : new Date(),
                "Main-Class"          : mainClassName,
                "Class-Path"          : configurations.runtime.collect{ "lib/"+it.getName() }.join(' ') 
            )
        }
}
```

accessing property files

```
    public Properties getProperties(String propFileName) throws IOException {
    String name = File.pathSeparator+"Properties"+File.separator+propFileName;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);

    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + name
            + "' not found in the classpath");
    }
    props.load(inputStream);

    return props;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code used to load the file. Given the stack trace, my guess is that you're not doing it correctly. There is no trace of a ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() call here.

Answer (score 3):

Everything under `src/main/resources` (not `src/main/resource`) is automatically included in the Jar. You can verify this by unpacking the Jar.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Type-o, will edit. I am able to verify that the file(s) is included in the jar, but don't understand why i am getting the above error

Comment: Hard to say. My best bet is that there is something wrong with how the resource is read.

Comment: Access property files via the below method

 `public Properties getProperties(String propFileName) throws IOException {
     String name = File.pathSeparator+"Properties"+File.separator+propFileName;
  Properties props = new Properties();
     InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);

     if (inputStream == null) {
         throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + name
             + "' not found in the classpath");
     }
     props.load(inputStream);

     return props;
 }`

Comment: Please put this into your question to make it more readable. `File.pathSeparator` seems wrong.

Comment: @KingJahfy: The classloader uses / as separator. Always. Whatever the platform is. Don't use File.saparator, nor File.pathSeparator. And the path must not start with a /.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you! that was the issue indeed i noticed it after taking the property files out of the Properties folder the classloader was able to locate it. I will use the / separator when dealing with the classloader. Thanks again